the liann.dev arg
Here is all I know about this ARG. I wasn’t able to reach the end. I also add findings by Shymain. You can read more about their finding and ideas in their google doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10BKQYlZKRFtf6aWeYRIlJUor-2-XenPnRgKFjQOI00w/edit.
I found a video id in a comment of a comment of a markiplier video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qquglT7Knfg ) by a channel that has “wrong place. Awn7mFktpB4” in their description (Shymain notes that it had “You saw me, right?” before) and a single youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wF8pcfjt8f4) that also has that id and does not seem relevant. This youtube video untitled “[BROADCAST SIGNAL FOUND]” is the starts of the ARG.
Here is a transcription of what I could understand from the video:

This is not a test, the United States department of defense has issued
an emergency broadcast to all citizens. At approximately eleven forty-
four pm eastern standard time, the Soviet Union launched a nuclear
strike on America. In response, a doomsday device has been triggered
following the detection of hostile nuclear arms. In ten minutes, all
human life will be eradicated, and the remaining world will be left
blanketed in nuclear fallout. This message serves as an apology to all
those who remain on this earth. We wish you a quick and easy death.
Our strength as a country as been put to the test and the enemy as
discovered our unwavering will. We depart this world with pride and
honor having proven America keeps its promises. You are advised to
convene with your loved ones and say your finals goodbyes. There is
nothing more you can do. There is nowhere to go. You will not survive.
There will be no further news following this message. This concludes
this emergency broadcast. God bless America.

The channel who uploaded the video has this in their channel description: “Technically a scientist with cold, dead hands.”.
At the end of the video there is a link to https://www.liann.dev/. There are other things in the video, such as weird audio. Shymain also points out that the list of US states given in the video lacks Ohio. But all those elements don’t seem to matter for now.
First thing you see when you go to that website is some kind of boot screen:
 LIANN BIOS Ver 2.9

  Copyright (C) 1956, Bureau of Nuclear Defense and Security
  CPU: BRL Ionian 600
  Experimental components: IU-21.09.22 see manual for additional specification

  Memory Test: 2096064K OK
      Checking root directory ...OK
      Detecting personality core ...FOUND
      Testing intelligence ...OK
      Assessing artificial sanity ...SUBOPTIMAL
      Detecting external drives ...NONE FOUND

  Press H to exit graphical boot up
      Generating GUI ...OK
      Detecting webcam ...FOUND
      Detecting microphone ...FOUND

  Initializing external servers...

if you read it you see you can press H to “exit graphical boot up”. If you press H you will be dropped in some kind of terminal, messing around there are three users: wadler, tdavis, and amoore. I assume at some point we can figure out the passwords of those users to access their files but cracking them might be possible.
If you go the regular route, there are some challenges after you made some kind of character sheet.
The first level is some kind of working memory test. There is a html comment that says “ She did not want to follow orders... ”
Then there is a maze where you control a light that starts on the top left with the arrow keys. The exit is at the bottom right. I made a cheat for it:
.flashlight {
    background-image: none!important;
}

There is a html comment that says “ ...then fell into dark halls... ”.
After that, there is a puzzle where when you click on a button, it enables the button you clicked on and disables all the neighbor buttons, you must enable all buttons to proceed. There is a html comment that says “ ...and made a lucky guess. ”
Then there will be some audio, and you will be asked to say what you hear, it’s NATO alphabet for “COUNT”.
Then you have to give the words to complete a sentence, the full sentence is:
“This Pangram contains four a’s, one b, two c’s, one d, thirty e’s, six f’s, five g’s, seven h’s, eleven i’s, one j, one k, two l’s, two m’s, eighteen n’s, fifteen o’s, two p’s, one q, five r’s, twenty-seven s’s, eighteen t’s, two u’s, seven v’s, eight w’s, two x’s, three y’s, & one z.” so the answer is “fifteen”. Pretty neat sentence! Shymain points out that to find that answer we had to COUNT the os.
Then we have a classic caesar code to crack:
sp hld l wtzy mzcy zq wtklcod -> he was a lion born of lizards
Then it gets a bit harder, we are given a book. One idea is to find the non encrypted book. We can do that because numbers aren’t “encrypted” and we can see a number: #1059, it is the ebook “The World Set Free”, we can find it on project gutenberg and the title is the answer (case doesn’t matter). Shymain noticed it is a vigenere cipher and cracked it, finding the key: “leoszilard”.
Then this is the last challenge for the fake ending, it’s a book cipher and if you use what’s directly given to you: 2:5:1:5:4-7, that is chapter 2, section 5, paragraph 1, line 5, words 4 to 7: “war was becoming impossible”, the website will tell you that it’s the end:  but it actually isn’t and if you give another answer you will get the “real” ARG.
Here is the code that checks for that:
onClick: () => { 'T6VSxRpFfY2ZSvVayLZNn4UgrzZczx9XC0YKRdH6HbU=' === i() (e.toLowerCase()).toString(m()) ? s.setOpenLevel(6) : 'G6aovlPVpvH/hynIkMyNeDh6265h8c4/L6dcoyxXw6I=' === i() (e.toLowerCase()).toString(m()) && s.setOpenLevel(7) },

We can get the real input for our book cipher by moving the window around and finding 2:2:9:2:7-8 under it (it is under all the windows staring from the NATO alphabet sound level window), it is chapter 2, section 2, paragraph 9, line 2, words 7 to 8: “woman’s soul” (replace the ’ with a ' though)
Now in the new page there is a html comment that says
“They weren't sure of the cause of death, but I know it wasn't a quick one. She suffered.”
There are also three images on this page.
“Scene of death.”, the file is called “deadmentellnotales.png”:

“Corpse contents. (1/2)”, the file is called “amoorepuzzle_p1.png”:

“Corpse contents. (2/2)”, the file is called “amoorepuzzle_p2.png”:

Those black borders around the paper might be important, also the folds match, so it is the same piece of paper. I analyzed the images in fotoforensic and read the strings but didn’t find anything interesting.
I believe the cipher here is an ADFGX cipher, which doesn’t seem to be trivial to crack.
The number of columns isn’t the same and is an odd number, maybe this arrangement means something. There doesn’t seem to be any place to input our answer for this step. There is also the number 5 and I don’t know what it’s for, maybe it’s to say it’s an ADFGX cipher (5 letters)? or maybe it’s the key length of the cipher, although that’s not probable because the encrypted text is 44 characters long, which is 2²×11 and key lengths are apparently usually multiple of the length of the encrypted text (so probably 4).
I tried breaking the cipher with https://github.com/glitchassassin/adfgvx-solver with key length 2, 4, 5 and 11 but got nothing interesting. I believe it didn’t work because our input is ADFGX and not ADFGVX. Another reason it could have not worked is if the original text was in german (it might be german because I saw mention of a german officer during the first world war in the code). I found another program https://www.cryptool.org/en/ct2/downloads that can break ADFGX and got “HE5POSSI7OS55ETHEREWE4” with key length 5, “HS6NDDERNESANDTHATWA7R” wit key length 4, both for english. “N5WOLLT7OL55NGENUNDN4” for german and key length 5. For some reason it got stuck at 50% for german and key length 4. By using AAAGXDFADADFGADFFFDAAXDGGADXDGFXDAXADFGDFAXA for input (reading the first column then the second), english and key length 5 we get ISSSANDTHE9SOFSUC44USA. None of this I can make sense of. I think we have to make use of the murder scene somehow to continue forward.
I wasn’t able to progress further, so I decided to come back to that terminal I talked about before. The shell only has cd and ls and boot (to re enable graphical boot up), unless you go to a user’s directory when you can then cat a bunch of files that are there, you can also only ls the current directory, and you can’t cd / nor cd ~, only cd .. or cd users. You can go down a users’ directory but you need a password (I have to point out that it doesn’t make sense how root can’t access any user directory). I tried the some passwords for each users but with no luck.
I also found in the js code: I was cut off short, but you are a new body.<br/>While it is still capable try to make sense of what is left.<br/>Look inside the network.<br/><br/>The key is found in fours. and It took me decades to accept that I\'d never be free.\n.
Shymain was able to find two of the three passwords.
They found that by inputting the copyright year from the graphical boot up (they draw attention to the possibility that more information in the graphical boot up might be helpful) in the initial survey, we were able to find a new page with information on wadler:

we can then observe that there are dots under certain letters. And by combining these letters they were able to find wadlers’ password: “lebendmaschine”. Which means living machine in german. Now if we type “cd wadler lebendmaschine” in the terminal, we can access his notes:
log_8:
WEEK ONE

My living quarters are not particularly desirable. I have no more room than an 
bachelor's student living in a dormitory, but the facility they have granted me is
more than a significant upgrade from my previous lab. Additionally, I have been 
assigned two partners to aid in the final construction of my project. They both 
appear to be intelligent, but time will tell how they fare in pioneering a new age 
of technology. I suspect the engineer, who goes by the name of Alexis Moore, will 
be more useful as an experienced engineer. She has already taken great interest in 
my current progress.

log_33:
SIMMERING WAR

I believe American intelligence still thinks I am a security risk despite the hoops 
they jumped through to bring me to this position. I suppose I am lucky my research 
was important enough to them that they will continue to let me lead the project. 
Regardless, it troubles me that there is something they are not telling my team about 
their intentions with my project. Frau Moore was questioned about the progress we are 
making on the machine and claims to have overheard concerns about Soviet movements to 
mass produce thermonuclear weapons. I am curious to know more about the state of the 
arms race, but it is not of concern for our work--allegedly.

Dr. Davis seemed particularly tight-lipped about this topic. 
He is most certainly hiding something from us.

log_7b:
STATE SPONSORSHIP

My requests to continue research on the Schwarzevenenpilz have been ignored for a 
while, but it appears I have made friend within the intelligence agency. I will be 
granted subjects to refine the cognitive ability of my machine and they have guaranteed 
these will be English-speakers.

Now that the machine is more refined, I would additionally like to test a theory on 
the vitality of the fungus's hosts. I suspect that by having a constant host I will 
be able to achieve more coherent thoughts by channeling previous data through a single 
processor.

log_264:
GROWING THEORY

It appears that my previous theory held truth to it. Having a single subject to channel 
the fungus's cognitive ability through has yielded in valuable results. As Frau Moore 
continues testing the new system, I have noticed a personality begin to shine through the
machine's answers. Upon request of a profile of the current subject and comparing the 
notes to certain patterns in test results I believe that I can confirm the personalities match.
Difficulty ensues knowing that the parasite is able to communicate through distances, I 
suspect through its spores, which could result even in delayed communication between parent 
parasite and host. This means if I insist on testing whether this personality is a result of 
the living host, I will have to eliminate the current host, preventing me from reconnecting it 
to see if the removed host's personality resurfaces.

Regardless, I will eventually have to test this. My friendly connection in the CIA is particularly 
ecstatic about this progress, and claims that if we are able to connect the machine to Soviet
spies and sympathizers then we may be able to predict the movements of the Soviet Union. 
I dare to think beyond this. The spores used for communication may be able to be incorporated 
into an inhalant which more quickly allows the fungus to attach to a host. Distances will be
an important factor, but it would allow for more direct espionage on the enemy.

I will request more human subjects shortly.

log_2d1:
CROSS CHECK

Dr. Davis has grown on me. He has an endearing charm like a little brother, but with the
intelligence of a well-read scientist. Because of this, I had hoped that he would be able 
to aid me by double checking my work and provide new ideas on how to progress. Unfortunately, 
it seems he has a faint heart. 
I understand this work is not for all, so I have taken precautions. Dr. Davis will aid me 
whether he would like to or not.

log_2f1:
UNFORTUNATE DEVELOPMENT

The inhalant seems to have worked, but the host is experiencing adverse health effects. This 
is to be expected, but I wonder if these effects are exaggerated due to the host not having 
made a direct connection to the mother fungus. However, the machine's knowledge of physics 
appears to have increased, so there must still be communication between spores. I do hope he
comes into better health.

log_320:
SUBJECT THREE

[CORRUPTED FILE]

Ð~G¿]ÈU#Ëé¨·¿¢îÛ¤TìvöTúüôÀ#␆üw5½_¸÷j$)Ö¡@YÉb¸R5ÆÃ©Ûüì2␖ö¡ûiù¶×áûG}ZÍàVÌÒE¤ÕÔåÏiï¼^À¿{çóáSÑ¦-
¨m¶ó·ÓÝÒ^ÈÀ¨Ã¿-¥ 6Æ÷¨®Ö¬Áá|ÑÎÁÀSã9øDÒt
²·3f£w␛ßäO¡×³ÑÐØÕÌÈ¡$Æ²{Ü␋]ÑÚ¯1öøÈ}Ò÷ÛøÏ²¸rÆzÙÖaÅ¹÷oÕêüÁ½sÝôæÔóÕÄJ¦wË³Ý¾ü¹ÝöÈù¨æúâ ¨£Ä2{ú¨¶ÖÙ
ÙºGÄÐØßÙ«fáÜì÷ó¨9í¶¨Ùü{÷ÛØ
´ÉÅÖÕâË¨Í2¨½ÛÏí·ªîëà¦Á³Ø±Ï¼Íý ¶Ó·¼¨ÒÔÌ¨¿¨ÌÚÛÜÀÅßðªÍÈªÕêÌÖöªÙÄüÚ ¨¿ßÙÛÖªßØ³üÝÄ±Ò±¸ëÓÎÏ¨ØªÓÜÅÈ¨ ÙÜÌ¸É¦³Ù¿ÚÛÜª±ÀªäßÎËÖ»ÜÙÄÀÙÙ¨Õ±ß¿ÍÖÕÀÜªÚàÓ¨ÜÀÍÀËÖª½×ÀÜ²¿ÓÀÎÖÐÙ¿ßÙªßÀÓÜ¨ÜÍÜÐÒǐ␊ÜÖªÖÜ±ÙØ¨ÜÀÀÒË¨ÓÀÌÏÖÀÄÖª±ÜßÖÖª¨À²ÙÀÖ¦ÚÜÈª ÜÀ¨Ö²Ü²ÌÙßÜª²Ü␛àÅÖÚ¨ÈÙßÖ␛ÀÜÅÖÜÀÖÀßÍßÛÖÀª¸ÈÛÖÙÀØÍÈ²ØÄÀßÐÚÓÈ¨ÍªßÙÖÀÛÜÈ¨²ÚÖÜÖÀÛªÈÍÖÜ␛ª²ÜàËÌÓØÈÄªÎÜÖÜÄªÅ␛ÖÖª²Ûß±ÙÜ±ªÈÀßÓßÜÀËß²ÓÛÛÖÀ²ÀÎÀÖßÙ²Ûª²␅␗À±ÙÜ±¨²×ÀÏÜÐ±ØÙÀ²

Shymain notes that we now know that amoore is Alexis Moore, that the german word "Schwarzevenenpilz" from the notes means black vein fungus (which reminds us of another puzzle) and the corrupted file which might be important.
Looking at the corrupted file with https://binvis.io/ i find some interesting patterns:
Detail, cluster:

Detail, scan:

Entropy:

I am however not skilled enough to know what do to about this nor what it means.
Shymain wasn’t able to find tdavis’ password but did progress by noticing that the first letter of each color in the survey spelled “IAMREBORN”. They then had the idea to input these colors clockwise from the top in the working memory test, which, surely enough, revealed a new page:

This page has the following html comment: “ My eyes and ears for a long while, even if his mind was broken. ”. Shymain says “I'm really not even sure where to start on this one. It intuitively feels like it should be some sort of column transposition cipher given the lines where the padding is shifted by one because of the dots in them, and the third piece of paper's bottom row. The difficulty here is that I can't seem to find any variant where 15 characters is enough, especially when multiple of those characters repeat. Also, it couldn't really be some sort of Polybius variant cipher since the digits here range from 0-9 instead of the desired 1-5.”
Shymai was able to progress further in the ADFGX page (although not directly on the ADFGX) and tie it back to amoore. They point out that the five could be a “ち” and that it could be a suggestion to use chi-squared analysis to break the cipher. They found that by running the original deadmentellnotales.png image through a steganography tool, there was an hidden zipped image in the image, called “monthlyreport.png”:

Shymain noticed that the word “bluejay” was highlighted and surely enough, it was amoore’s password. Which gives us access to his files:
log_10:
IN COMPARISON

I got a chance to work with ENIAC and previous prototype analog computers, 
but what Adler's doing is far beyond any of that. When I first read the write-up 
I thought he was just some crazed fanatic that they recruited out of superstition, 
but no. It's all real; able to form crude answers to questions without any direct 
instruction or wiring. However, it's responses are very odd, even if generally 
correct. It answers in a mix of languages, as if it can't decide which one to use.
Mostly it prints out pure gibberish. I'm still trying to figure out how it works, 
but Adler has been guarded on some of its features, particularly how it processes 
data. 

There's also an odd plant he's brought to the basement. He insists we help cultivate
it, but I don't see how it's relevant to anything other than his vague 'biology
research'.

I still have my suspicions about his alliances. The higher-ups are trying to 
whitewash the new recruits' ledgers from deep Nazi party affiliation and related 
war crimes. Adler's profile, when we were assigned to assist him, seemed to be 
similarly cleared, but that ugly scar on his cheek tells me all I need to know. 
I'm keeping a close eye on him for now.

log_29:
AN UNFORTUNATE DISCOVERY

I had to pull a few strings, but I managed to get my hands on the papers I've been 
looking for. Lucky me, they keep the place well organized. They haven't begun the 
redaction process yet, but the information is sparse regardless. I feel as though I 
should be excited to have confirmed my suspicions, but the more I read the further 
my heart sinks. 
Some of these men were the cause of thousands of deaths, the amount of human rights
violations here should warrant their deaths, not an elevated standing within the US.
Adler's one of those. There are few details, but it's clear his 'biology research' 
involved human experimentation on unwilling prisoners. 

I still have contacts in Germany. They should be able to dig up more information on 
these guys admist the chaos. When the world quiets down we'll put them on public trial.


Theo looks like he's sick. I'm not sure what happened, but he's grown more antsy than 
usual. Can't even make eye contact with me when I say good morning. 
Did Adler do something?

log_5b:
PROGRESS

The machine is beginning to output more impressive results. I'm not sure what
heralded the change, but it's certainly a welcome one. Adler's put me on duty of 
testing how significant this development is. 
I swear we're going to end up causing a ink shortage with how many tests I'm
having it print out. So far the computer seems to be giving more coherent answers,
and primarily in English for once. Instead of outputting gibberish with a few
words in between, it's developed into a sort of stuttering speech.

As much as I hate Adler, I'm rather excited to see this machine become 
a marvel of technology. Imagine it's use to accelerate research.

log_13f:
THE ROOM

Theo asked me about the room. I thought it was storage. 

It is storage.

Apparently there was only one person when he'd been inside. There's two now. 
I tried to talk with them. The woman is barely responsive, it looks like she's 
had incisions made at the back of her neck. The man is similarly damaged and 
can speak, but he doesn't seem aware of his situation. They both look infected.
Dark veins and deteriorating flesh. It looks almost like the roots of our
resident Nazi's plant.
Just standing there feels like I'm in a nightmare.

The rest of the room is what I would expect from a mad scientist. Concrete walls,
dark stains that can only be dried blood, a small slab that must function as a
crude operating table, and it smells like piss. 
Is this what the plant is for? I tried to find any notes that Adler might have 
written down, but there's nothing here except them, some surgical tools, and that 
all too familiar dark mass.
How could I have been so blind to this? I've been too focused on finding old proof
that I didn't care to look right in front of me. 

Instructions are to wait until tensions are down, but the corruption already runs
deep and the arms race won't end until either we or the Soviets are nothing but
dust. I can't stand idly while some sick experiment happens right behind me. 
I'm going to burn down that fucking plant and its forsaken owner with it.

log_212:
A DEAR FRIEND

Theo is getting worse. His face is covered in black spots. It almost looks like
he's rotting from the inside out and he seems out of it. Way out of it. 
Keeps muttering and saying all this nonsense. I can barely get a coherent 
conversation out of him anymore. 
God dammit, I need to find where Adler keeps his notes. This has to be his
fault. He's going to turn Theo into one of the poor souls in the storeroom.

log_2c6:
NOTES

I spent all night searching for these fucking notes. My German vocabulary isn't
this good, but it's clear enough he's infected Theo with some sort of parasite.
This little shit is psychopathic enough to not even name Theo. It's all just
'host this', 'subject that.' 
It must be the fungus he's studying, Schwarzevenenpilz.
Worse, I don't think there's a way to save him. How do you expel a parasite
that grows into your system? As if I could just grab it from his throat and
pull it out like a fishing line.

I'm going to kill that man with my own two hands.

log_41c:
QUIET

It's starting to get really lonely here.
It's just me and what remains of Theo. He's practically gone now, in spirit
at least. But he's been writing. So much writing he's giving LIANN a run for
its money. The machine's also been acting odd since Adler went missing. It's 
started making less and less sense, as if all our progress vanished. It'll print
series of numbers without prompt, then Theo will take them and start writing 
more on top. Part of me hopes there's something real behind the scribbles.
A code that when deciphered will tell me he's alright or that he wants me to
change television channels.

I brought down a television for him. Managed to route the satellite so that we
can get signal down here. I remembered he said he was a fan of Batman at some 
point, and I think that little bit of him that's left appreciates it since he'll
sometimes pause and just watch.

I'll have to keep the operation running solo for now. Draft up some fake updates 
for some officers, all of that great stuff.

log_bc4:
NETWORK

I've been compiling all of Theo's notes and I was right!
There's something readable under all of this nonsense. I've spent the last two 
weeks combing through all his chicken scratch and translating what I can find.
All this time he's been trying to talk to me... and some others. It's complicated,
but I think I've figured out what he's been trying to say. 

LIANN is not just the machine, but also the fungus that Adler brought. Somehow it's
managed to exist as a sort of data storage and processor, and the way it creates
what appears like thought is through the memories of those it leeches off of. From 
what I can tell there are at least a dozen people who've been hosts for the fungus. 
Sometimes Theo's able to get out actual names, but it's more like he's having
conversations with them and they're all speaking through him.
I imagine having a dozen people trying to speak inside your head doesn't make it 
the easiest to think coherently. 

I need time to let this sink in.

log_13ee:
GONE

There's nothing left for me here. Theo's stopped writing, and I just can't bring 
myself to put him out of his misery. He's my friend, for Christ's sake. 

I took care of the other two of Adler's victims a while ago. After discovering 
how LIANN really works, I don't think I can let it keep running. If they figure 
it out it'll just lead to more human exploitation, turning minds to slop just to 
try and get some information or create a more powerful central intelligence. Why 
have scientists when you can just suck out their brains and keep the information 
eternal?

I'll try to spread the word, let the people know what's been happening under 
their noses. The internal corruption, the Nazis acting as if they did nothing wrong...
Then I'll come back. Burn the records, stop anyone from figuring out what really 
happened. And I won't leave him alone.

Shymain notes that “log_41c.txt seems to be directly referencing the long strings of numbers that we see over in tdavispuzzle_final.png”
Here are all interesting strings i extracted from the website: https://0bin.net/paste/wSoZ42KV#74r6-KVHQZkVrGe1v59Jfbl9KNNBPT6dEg0K3mF8X6k.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!
